# Symlink multiple targets in buildout recipe

Tags: python, buildout

I have a buildout recipe that creates a symlink to a file. The relevant section looks like this and works perfectly:

```
[symlinks]
recipe = cns.recipe.symlink
symlink = targetname1 = linkname1
```

Now I want to link to another file -- that is, a different source pointing at a different target. I thought this would work, but it doesn't:

```
[symlinks]
recipe = cns.recipe.symlink
symlink = targetname1 = linkname1
symlink = targetname2 = linkname2
```

Now neither of the two symlinks gets created.

I can solve the problem by doing this, but it's very clunky, especially when I want to make more than 2 symlinks:

```
[symlinks1]
recipe = cns.recipe.symlink
symlink = targetname1 = linkname1

[symlinks2]
recipe = cns.recipe.symlink
symlink = targetname2 = linkname2
```

How do I put multiple symlinks in a single section in the buildout recipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to write the different links on different lines. Like this:

```
[symlinks]
recipe = cns.recipe.symlink
symlink =
    targetname1 = linkname1
    targetname2 = linkname2
```

You can add as many links as you like by putting each one on a new line.

You can read more about it in the source code for the recipe [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cns.recipe.symlink/). The documentation on that page above is unfortunately rather poor though.